# How to do addition in integer in simple tag in Apache XML camel route

Tags: tags, addition

```
<setHeader name="hfour">
 <simple resultType="java.lang.Integer">4</simple> 
</setHeader>

<setHeader name="transstart">
 <simple>{body.indexOf(":20:")}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

Need to add this two header

I tried + ++ still simple considering as string not as operand. Please suggest how to design simple tag to do increment by four. If not possible need to use any other language. Correctly other codes cannot be added

Comment: I use a script to write groovy code to do any integer manipulation. Then set that value in a exchange property to use later in the route.